# Windows Media Service 2008 configuration guide?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows

I am using Windows Media Service 2008 on Windows Server 2008 x64. I have downloaded and installed 3 components -- Server, Core and Admin.

I want to find some tutorial for a newbie to configure Windows Media Service step by step, e.g. host some wmv media files and so that external user could use Windows Media Player to play with.

Any recommended tutorials?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the [Windows Media Services 2008 Deployment Guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730848%28WS.10%29.aspx) on TechNet.  It should get you up and running.  (navigation is over on the left)